# How to make 400 samples of 50 values

Tags: r

I am suppose to make 400 samples whereby each sample contains 50 values from my dataset. I want to do it in a for-loop but I don't know how to do it.
Below is my code so far

```
 set.seed(1)
 alldata     = humangenes$GC ### I am storing the value of GC variable 
 truemean    = mean(alldata)
 nsamples    = 400   ###number of samples I want to make
 r = data.frame()

  for (j in 1:nsamples) {
        mysample = sample(alldata, 50, replace = F) # Each gene can  
        only be picked once

  ##I don't know what to do next
   }
```

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Zheyuan Li...Thanks. Your solution works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a loop, you could get a matrix result like such

```
set.seed(1)
alldata <- rnorm(1000, 1,5) # create sample data
nsamples <- 400             #number of samples I want to make
sampSize <- 50              #size of each sample    

r = <- matrix(nrow = nsamples, ncol = sampSize)

for (j in 1:nsamples) {
     r[j,] <- sample(alldata, sampSize, replace = FALSE)
}
```

Which could then be converted to a dataframe if necessary by doing

```
df <- data.frame(r)
```

As Zheyuan noted in a comment, the loop could be replaced with

```
r <- replicate(nsamples, sample(alldata, sampSize, replace = F))
```